# Alter column from nvarchar to DateTime SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

The data is present in the column in `nvarchar` format, I need to change the data type of that column to `Datetime`.

There is another problem the data saved has 2 formats one is `dd/mm/yyyy` and other is `mm/dd/yyyy`. How can I achieve this?

I have tried the following but obviously I have got an error.

Used

```
UPDATE SalesRegister 
SET followup =  PARSE(FollowUpDate AS datetime);
```

Error:

> Error converting string value '20/07/2014' into data type datetime using culture ''

Can someone guide me with this query? I was thinking one more way of doing this which can be first converting the format in mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy and than apply the alter statement. But I don't know this either.

Comment: You cannot generically distinguish between the two date formats.  What is 04/07/2016 -- July 4th or April 7th?  So, you have a big problem, because the data is ambiguous.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yeah that's the issue, but is there a way to achieve this if we ignore this issue

Comment: Which **version** of SQL Server (2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, 2014) are you using?

Comment: Add a new column (date type), set that column to the original value, converted to date. Remove original column. Rename new column.